# increase and decrease a number for each item of array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

Server sends data that is an array of objects. I iterate through them in the template with `v-for`.

I need to show how many selected in a span for each item when a user clicks the increase and decrease buttons. I simplify my data with following example. The `0` value is static. How can I increase and decrease the value for each item when a user clicks the buttons?

```
let data = [
{type: 'car', color: 'white'
},{type: 'car', color: 'black'}
,.....]

<div v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
  <div>
     {{item.color}}
     <div class='btn-group'>
      <button>increase</button>
       <span>0</span>  <----- how many selected
      <button>decrease</button>
     </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, check this example.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in records"
      :key="index">
      <div>
        {{ item.color }}
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button @click="increase(index)">
            +
          </button>
          <span>{{ item.val || 0 }}</span>
          <button @click="decrease(index)">
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      records: [
        { type: 'car', color: 'white' },
        { type: 'car', color: 'black' },
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchApi();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchApi() {
      axios.get('/your-url')
        .then((response) => {
          this.records = response.data.records.map((record) => {
            return {
              ...record,
              val: 0,
            };
          });
        });
    },
    increase(index) {
      this.records[index].val += 1;
    },
    decrease(index) {
      this.records[index].val -= 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: thankyou but val 0 is not available in server response.

Comment: I've updated the example. You can see that I'm mapping the response data list from api call and adding a `val: 0` property. In this way, all the records will have dynamically set default 0 vals, and you can use the values in the similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<div id="example-1">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <div>
       {{item.color}}
       <div class='btn-group'>
        <button v-on:click="addOne(index)">increase</button>
         <span>{{counter[index]}}</span>
        <button v-on:click="minusOne(index)">decrease</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

And your Vue code is like this:

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    items: [
      {type: 'car', color: 'white'},
      {type: 'car', color: 'black'}
    ],
    counter: []
  },
  methods: {
    addOne(index) {
      this.$set(this.counter, index, this.counter[index] + 1);
    },
    minusOne(index) {
      this.$set(this.counter, index, this.counter[index] - 1);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.counter = Array(this.items.length).fill(0);
  }
})
```